# How to skim through a page, element by element, and determine which element I'm looking at?

Tags: c#, selenium

Premise:
I'm trying to write a selenium program that is as abstract as possible, so that when I make new tests, there is minimal work required. The idea that I came up with is for me to iterate through the elements on the page, then I would take the element, all of the attributes, parent, children,(which I can find out later, not necessarily in scope for this question though) and other such things, and then I'd pack this into an object that I made called 'Element'. After running this and getting every element on the page, I'll make a change to the page i.e. tab out of the text box, click a button etc., and then do the iteration all again, and note the differences.

The Question:
How do I start from the top of the page, and iterate through each element that exists on the page. I want to include elements including but not limited to things such as labels, divs, textboxes, buttons, everything. Everything that is an element, I want to find it, and add it to the collection.

Side tasks after:
After this I'll try to locate it's attributes, and then determine if it has any children, and if it has any parents.

I've found methods online regarding how to find an element by something like id or name or other, and I could find multiple elements like this and pack it into a collection, but I don't see how this would help out my specific case because then I would have to make a case for every single type of element which sounds like more work than I'd want.

EDIT: THIS WILL NOT INCLUDE THE HEAD, ONLY THE BODY.

Comment: Do you want to include the head section of a page or just the document body? Also, what are you going to do about the possibility of iframes as they have their own document? Do you care about labels and spans and divs or just input elements, drop downs, unlinked lists and list items, links and buttons?

Comment: Thanks for the response as it appears I was not specific enough. Not the head, all elements in the body. this includes but is not limited to things such as labels, divs, textboxes, everything. Everything that is an element, I want to find it, and add it to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all child elements calling FindElements from another IWebElement like this

```
IWebElement body = Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("Body"));
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> bodyChilds = body.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*"));
```

That will return all child elements of the body.
Then you can iterate over every element in the list finding its elements to know if they have childs or not.

Regarding the attributes part, as far as i know it's not possible just with selenium, but there are easy to find examples out there on how to do it with javascript